# How to Use wget

Tags: download, wget

i am not able to use wget in my ubuntu system.. whenever i try to download anything for example,

```
sudo wget http://www.cyberciti.biz/here/lsst.tar.gz
```

what i get is

```
–2009-09-18 10:15:15– hxxp://www.cyberciti.biz/here/lsst.tar.gz
Resolving http://www.cyberciti.biz... 74.86.48.99
Connecting to http://www.cyberciti.biz|74.86.48.99|:80… ^C
```

The above is same for any website.
i am able to do sudo apt-get install and this is the evidence that i am connecting to the internet. But for wget case i am not able to. Is there any config settings that i need to do,
like configuring the wgetrc file?
Please help me...

Comment: Any errors occur, or does it just hang?

Comment: btw: why do you use sudo when calling wget? you don't need any superuser rights for downloading do you?

Comment: He may saving it to a dir where he needs Sufi to write to.

Comment: May or may not be related: *[Why does wget give an error when executed with sudo, but works fine without?](https://superuser.com/questions/979113/why-does-wget-give-an-error-when-executed-with-sudo-but-works-fine-without)*

Answer (score 4):

Try using cURL:

```
curl -O http://www.cyberciti.biz/here/lsst.tar.gz
```

As far as I know cURL is not installed in Ubuntu by default, so you will need to:

```
sudo apt-get install curl
```