# Why does wget give an error when executed with sudo, but works fine without?

Tags: bash, sudo, wget

I tried the following command:

```
$ wget -q --tries=10 --timeout=20 --spider http://google.com
```

(From [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17291233/5316879). I want to check my internet connection in bash.)

I get following output:

```
Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
--2015-09-28 09:55:50--  http://google.com/
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:3128... connected.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: http://www.google.de/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=k_IIVreaN-yH8Qfe1Yu4CA [following]
Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
--2015-09-28 09:55:50--  http://www.google.de/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=k_IIVreaN-yH8Qfe1Yu4CA
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:3128... connected.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Remote file exists and could contain further links,
but recursion is disabled -- not retrieving.
```

Seems OK, however running the cmd with `sudo`, I receive this:

```
Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
--2015-09-28 09:55:27--  http://google.com/
Resolving google.com (google.com)... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘google.com’
```

I need this line in a script, which I call with `sudo` and so it always fails.

Can somebody tell me the reason for this?  How can I work around that?

Comment: Sorry, I actually wanted to create the questions in _AskUbuntu_. Not sure if On-Topic here...

Comment: It's on-topic here.

Comment: It would be Off-Topic there.

Comment: This looks like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Executing a random `wget` against google.com doesn't seem to be a good way of checking that an internet connection is working: for example, you might be on a connection that allows HTTP connections to Google but forbids the things your script really wants to do; or Google might forbid wget access to their site. What is the actual problem you have, for which you think that `sudo wget blah` is a potential solution?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You have a proxy defined in your environment.  Yours appears to be `127.0.0.1:3128`.

When you run `sudo`, the proxy environment variable isn't passed, which is why you can't directly resolve `google.com`.

You can see what proxy/proxies you have defined in your environment variables with this command:

```
env | grep proxy
```

*<sup><sub>[Additional information on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/3808/18979)</sub></sup>*

**Note:** If you want `sudo` to pass the HTTP proxy environment variable, try this:

```
sudo http_proxy="$http_proxy" wget -q --tries=10 --timeout=20 --spider http://google.com
```

You can also pass all environment variables using `sudo -E`:

```
sudo -E wget -q --tries=10 --timeout=20 --spider http://google.com
```

*<sup><sub>[Stack Overflow has other options for keeping the environment variable when `sudo`ing.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8633461/1038828)</sub></sup>*

Comment: OK, thank you very much for not only posting the answer, but also posting the links for explanation. Worked for me perfectly.

Comment: You can also use `sudo -E` to preserve environment variables

Comment: for only passing the http_proxy, wouldn't `sudo http_proxy=$http_proxy wget ...` be better? If you use that in any script you don't have to change it if the proxy changes.

Comment: Nice one, @Josef.  I've updated the answer with your suggestion.

Comment: You can also add `Defaults env_keep += "http_proxy ftp_proxy"` to `/etc/sudoers` to make sudo automatically preserve those env variables.