# Downloading file using WGET when run under CMD file

Tags: wget

I'm trying to download a photo from the internet but an error always occur.
I tried to run the command under a batch program ".cmd" with the following codes in it:
wget http://weather.is.kochi-u.ac.jp/SE/00Latest.jpg

but I always get the error:
Connecting to weather.is.kochi-u.ac.jp:80...
connect: No such file or directory

I tried several options such as --user --user-agent --proxy --tries but does not work.

I'm working from my office and we have a proxy server in order to get into the internet.  I'm not sure whether this affects my command using the wget.

I do have a command using powershell -Command and it works fine but could not run under task scheduler and so I opted to use the wget as most recommended this.  However, I could not seem to get it going when test trying it.

Anybody here can point me to the right direction?  I'm not a programmer or someone with great knowledge on that field but I'm knowledgeable enough to learn and understand.  TIA.

Comment: To me it's working fine... In CMD I go to *C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin* enter your command and download starts...

Answer (score 0):

Worked fine for me.

> 

C:\>wget.exe http://weather.is.kochi-u.ac.jp/SE/00Latest.jpg
--22:41:31--  http://weather.is.kochi-u.ac.jp/SE/00Latest.jpg
           => '00Latest.jpg'
Resolving weather.is.kochi-u.ac.jp... done.
Connecting to weather.is.kochi-u.ac.jp[133.97.166.237]:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 58,534 [image/jpeg]

100%[====================================>] 58,534        52.59K/s    ETA 00:00

22:41:32 (52.59 KB/s) - `00Latest.jpg' saved [58534/58534]


C:\>
(Some small changes...  I converted one back-quote to an apostraphe, and tabs aren't showing up quite right...  my main point of showing some sample output is, it worked fine.)

If it isn't working for you, my guess is that it's an issue with your Internet connectivity.  You might have a content blocker that prevents the HTTP connection.  Maybe an HTTP proxy needs to be used.  However, the wget command works fine.  So, from my test, I would say that the thing that you need to try fixing isn't your basic wget syntax.  If you do need to change the syntax, like referencing a web proxy, you may need to identify the settings another way (troubleshooting elsehow).  Can you visit the jpg file in any other web-grabbing software?

If you're distrusting whether wget is functioning right, there are multiple variations of wget, as well as other programs like curl that could be tried.  They'll probably act the same way, but if they don't, then you'll apparently have your answer.

Comment: After doing the 2nd fix suggested above and successfully running the command, I now think it might have been caused by the proxy setting.

Comment: @JMV: Please accept h0ch5tr4355's answer then, to give that person due credit.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax with a Proxy is:

```
C:\> wget -e http_proxy=127.0.0.1:3128 www.example.com
```

The IP/Port depends - of course - on your office's proxy.

Comment: Tried this... now it works

Comment: Using the "-e" option is new for me so thank you very much.

Comment: I once had the same question for windows (or a similar one http://superuser.com/questions/979113/why-does-wget-give-an-error-when-executed-with-sudo-but-works-fine-without) and so I noticed it is the same with windows, guess its because wget comes from linux natively